# <meta name="robots" duplicate issue

Tags: wp-head, noindex

I use WordPress
i have a problem on
I have inspected my site and there are 2 meta tags

```
 <meta name='robots' content='index, follow, max-image-preview:large, max-snippet:-1, max-video-preview:-1' />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
```

how do I delete one of them

```
(<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />)
```

Answer (score 1):

this question is too generic to be answered. You need to debug and understand where those 2 meta are created.
As a first step I would disaable all the plugin and enable one by one to see if it's coming from a plugin.